# java : What is the exact functionality of buffer.flip() method?

Tags: java-io, java.nio.file

try (FileOutputStream binFile = new FileOutputStream("data.dat");
             FileChannel binChannel = binFile.getChannel()) {

```
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
        byte[] outputBytes = "Hello World!".getBytes();
        buffer.put(outputBytes);
        long int1Pos = outputBytes.length;
        buffer.putInt(245);

        binChannel.write(buffer);

        java.io.RandomAccessFile ra = new java.io.RandomAccessFile("data.dat", "rwd");
        FileChannel channel = ra.getChannel();

        ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);

        channel.position(int1Pos);
        channel.read(readBuffer);
        readBuffer.flip();
        System.out.println("Int3 = " + readBuffer.getInt());
         } catch(IOException e){
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the Java docs on it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html

> Flips this buffer. The limit is set to the current position and then the position is set to zero. If the mark is defined then it is discarded.
>   After a sequence of channel-read or put operations, invoke this method to prepare for a sequence of channel-write or relative get operations. For example: